# sp.debug.js Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: sharepoint-online, visual-studio, jsom

So I am trying to add **sp.debug.js** into my project in **Visual Studio 2015** to get **intellisense** working for **JSOM** but the **intellisense** doesn't work and the **sp.debug.js** file (taken from SharePoint online /_layouts/15/sp.debug.sj) is giving me the below error, is the file foobar or am I missing something?

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Parsing error: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found a different solution to get intellisense to work when SharePoint is not installed on the development server:

Download each of the required below files from the SharePoint Online site:

**Url location:**

`https://<sharepoint online site url>/_layouts/15/<filename>`

**filenames:**

- init.js
- sp.js
- sp.core.js
- sp.debug.js
- sp.runtime.js

There are other optional files which you may require, download as necessary (ie. SP.UI.Dialog.js)

Then I added them into my project (I put them in a seperate folder for cleanliness) then I added a link to them in my _references.js file.

```
/// <reference path="../SharePointReferences/init.js" />
/// <reference path="../SharePointReferences/sp.js" />
/// <reference path="../SharePointReferences/sp.core.js" />
/// <reference path="../SharePointReferences/sp.runtime.js" />
/// <reference path="../SharePointReferences/sp.UI.Dialog.js" />
/// <reference path="../SharePointReferences/sp.debug.js" />
```

Set the files "Deployment Type" to "NoDeployment" as they exist on the server so we dont directly reference them.

**Set up the _references.js file**

You will need to also make sure that you have your _references.js file set up in VS properly, mine wasn't initially.

Go to Tools > Options > Text Editor > Javascript > Intellisense > References

Reference Group = Implicit (Web)

Add > "~/Scripts/_references.js"

Now you should get intellisense in your SharePoint Add In project.

See answer on [SharePoint hosted add-in intellisense not working for SP namespace](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/194165/sharepoint-hosted-add-in-intellisense-not-working-for-sp-namespace/195631#195631)

Comment: Edited answer to match requirements